# Linear Equations over $\{0,1\}$ with addition considered over $\mathbb Z$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Is there any way to solve a system of linear equations with both the coefficients and variables coming from $\{0,1\}$ but where addition is considered over the non-negative integers, not $\mathbb{F}_2$?

I have considered trying to solve such systems over $\mathbb{Q}$ and then interpreting the solution in that case:  If it is inconsistent then there is also no solution over $\{0,1\}$.  If there is a unique solution, then it is easy to check if that is a solution to my problem as well.  However, I don't know how to handle the case of infinitely many solutions having free variables.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By hand, or computationally? Software like Gurobi is great for this.  Really what you have is a "binary integer programming" problem (this is where you are trying to solve a system of linear equations, restricting your variables to be 0-1).

Solving by hand, there is really no way.  You can maybe find some ideas here: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~latte/theory.php
but again, it's more software based.  According to Wikipedia, these types of problems in general are NP-complete problem.

Answer (score 0):

The unknowns $(x_i)_{i\leq n}$ are in $\{0,1\}$ ; then the number of solutions is finite...

If I understand correctly your question, then one has a system $Ax=b$ where $A=[a_{i,j}]\in M_{p,n}(\{0,1\})$, $b=[b_i]$ with $b_i\in \{0,1\}$ are given, $x$ is as $b$ but is unknown.

We solve the system in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (with Gauss) ; we assume that there is more than one solution. Then the result is in the form : for every $i\leq k$, $x_i=f_i(x_{k+1},\cdots,x_n)$ where $f_i$ is an affine function and $x_{k+1},\cdots,x_n$ are arbitrary, that is, we obtain $2^{n-k}$ candidates. If $2^{n-k}$ is not a too great number, then we can conclude by brute force. Else we use the following fact: for every $i\leq p$, $cardinality(\{j;a_{i,j}x_j\not=0\})$ is $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I guess my question was not clear enough.  I was more interested in the case when the $b_i$ are arbitrary non-negative integers. I realize now from the first line of your answer that there will only ever be finitely many solutions, but I was wondering if there is any efficient way for finding them.  Thanks.